# Stay on selected item on drop down menu using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

What is happening is I'm trying to get the drop-down menu to STAY on what was selected but it keeps switching to the default after I hit submit. Can someone help me with the javascript code because I know for sure that's the issue? Thanks everyone I'm trying to self-learn this.

```js
 function GetSelectedItem(){
   var option = document.getElementById("locale").value;
}
//THIS WON'T WORK?
function StayOnSelectedItem(){
   var element = document.getElementById("locale");
   var value = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>My Website toolbar</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="languageswitcher.css">
  </head>
 
  <body>
 
    <header>
 
      <div id="country-select">
        <form action="" method = "get">
          <select id= "locale" name="locale">
   <option value="en_US">English(US)</option>
   <option value="en_GB">English(UK)</option>
                 <option value="bg_BG">Bulgarian</option>
                 <option value="cs_CS">Czech</option>
                 <option value="da_DK">Danish</option>
   <option value="de_DE">German</option>
   <option value="ek_GR">Greek</option>
   <option value="es_ES">Spanish</option>
              <option value="et_ET">Estonian</option>
   <option value="fi_FI">Finnish</option>
   <option value="fr_FR">French</option>
   <option value="hu_HU">Hungarian</option>
   <option value="it_IT">Italian</option>
   <option value="lt_LT">Lithuanian</option>
   <option value="lv_LV">Latvian</option>
   <option value="nl_NL">Dutch</option>
   <option value="no_NO">Norwegian</option>
   <option value="pl_PL">Polish</option>
   <option value="pt_PT">Portugese</option>
   <option value="ro_RO">Romanian</option>
   <option value="sk_SK">Slovak</option>
   <option value="sl_SL">Slovenian</option>
   <option value="sv_SE">Swedish</option>
          </select>
          <input value="Select" type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </header>
    <script src="languageswitcher.js"></script>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code you posted seems to be working in the run code snippet, although I don't see where you are using StayOnSelectedItem(), the ddlb retains my selection when I click on select.

Comment: On page reload, set the value for `select-input`

Comment: So if you copy and paste this code into notepad++ and open it up in a browser, my issue is when I select a different language for example Italian, what happens is it will take me to the link (the 1st function of javascript does that) but what happens is that the drop-down menu goes back to default (English US)

Comment: @Rayon May you please elaborate on what you mean by that Rayon? Thank you!

Comment: @Giorgio, Based on the server side script, you can make out whether value of `select` is posted or not.. If it is posted, set that value for `select-input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title

> Get selected text from a drop-down list (select box) using Javascript

is not the same question as your first sentence:

> What is happening is I'm trying to get the drop-down menu to STAY on what was selected but it keeps switching to the default after I hit submit.

To get the text from the selected option in a drop-down list, you use

```
var e = document.getElementById('locale');
var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
console.log(text);
```

To get a form to keep its values after clicking a button of the type submit, it should work this way by default. From what I know, browsers don't have a reason to want to clear a drop-down field when clicking a button of the type submit.

You can always test stopping the browser's default behavior by including `return false;` in the `onsubmit` event.

```
<input value="Select" type="submit" onsubmit="GetSelectedItem(); return false;" />
```

**Edit:** And from your comment replies, it seems your actual question is something else entirely. If you want to retain the value of a drop-down list AFTER having left the page, you will need to store the value somewhere (most commonly a cookie, SessionStorage or a server-side session which is outside of the scope of Javascript).

I recommend [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) if you want to use SessionStorage.

Comment: You are correct sorry I didn't write the title correctly!

Comment: "And from your comment replies, it seems your actual question is something else entirely. If you want to retain the value of a drop-down list AFTER having left the page, you will need to store the value somewhere (most commonly a cookie, SessionStorage or a server-side session which is outside of the scope of Javascript)."   Meaning I can't possibly make the drop down menu stay on what was selected using javascript?

Comment: Giorgio, I assume you quoted me to let me know that this is what you meant. If this is the case, you'll already find a link to an MDN article at the bottom of my answer that explains how to use SessionStorage to store data across visits (so even if you've left the page).

Comment: Got it thanks so much Sebastien, would this possibly work with PHP (server side) then because it isn't possible to do this with Javascript?

Comment: It IS possible with Javascript, if you use SessionStorage ([click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)). Using a server-sided language like PHP can also work (with [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)).

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much @Sébastien Vercammen  it didn't work when I tried but thank you for getting me into the right direction

Answer (score 0):

```
 function GetSelectedItem()
 {
     var index = document.getElementById("locale").selectedIndex;    
     alert("value =" + document.getElementById("locale").value); // show selected value
     alert("text =" + document.getElementById("locale").options[index].text); // show selected text 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tanvi but it didn't work for me :(